# Can .NET 6 minimal API endpoints have opt-out authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to code a small API where every endpoint should have auth enabled by default, because I don't want to repeat the same `[Authorize]` attribute or `.RequiresAuthorization()` call for every endpoint.

I did all the usual `.AddAuthentication()`, `.AddAuthorization()`, `.UseAuthentication()`, `.UseAuthorization()`, but no matter how I parameterized these, I couldn't get an Unauthorized response, unless I explicitly put on the attribute.

Since I have more endpoints that require auth than not, I'd prefer to just decorate the open ones with `[AllowAnonymous]`

I'm not even sure if it can be done with regular Web API/MVC, but I certainly couldn't find anything for the new minimal API approach.

Answer (score 8):

You can set a FallBackPolicy or DefaultPolicy

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
      .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
      .Build();
});
```

and than just use AllowAnonymous on your public apis

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had the same approach for controllers under the services.AddControllers() method, but since I don't use that with minimal api now, I was just wondering how to add it a global policy.

Comment: Doing the same with "DefaultPolicy" doesn't work. But works fine with "FallbackPolicy". Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can add the `AllowAnonymous` attribute to a minimal API endpoint like this:

```
app.MapGet("/hello", [AllowAnonymous] () => "Hello, World!");
```

Comment: Yes I know this part, but how do I make every other endpoint require authorization without any attribute is my main problem.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Although perhaps not the answer to the question, this does answer my own question I had: "how to allow anonymous requests on specific endpoints".